# How do you test a factory function with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How do I test the following code in Jest:

```
module.exports.ingestionFunctionFactory = (ingestObj, retry) => {
    if (ingestObj.pwg) {
        return () => imageRetrievers.retrieveImageFromProxy(ingestObj.uri, ingestObj.usr, ingestObj.pw, ingestObj.authType)
    } else {
        if (ingestObj.authType === "digest") {
            return () => imageRetrievers.retrieveFromDigestAuthURI(ingestObj.uri, ingestObj.usr, ingestObj.pw)
        } else {
            return () => imageRetrievers.retriveFromBasicAuthURI(ingestObj.uri, ingestObj.usr, ingestObj.pw)
        }
    }
```

I have tried the following test:

```
describe("FUNCTION: ingestionFunctionFactory", () => {
    let retrieveImageFromProxySpy
    const ingestObj = TEST_CONSTANTS.ingest

    beforeEach(() => {
        retrieveImageFromProxySpy = jest.spyOn(imageRetrievers, "retrieveImageFromProxy").mockImplementation(()=>null)
    })

    test("returns retrieveImageFromProxy if pwg is true", () => {
        const ingestFunction = pullIngest.ingestionFunctionFactory(ingestObj)

        ingestFunction()

        expect(retrieveImageFromProxySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ingestObj.uri, ingestObj.usr, ingestObj.pw, ingestObj.authType, true)
    })


    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks()
    })
    afterAll(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks()
    })
})
```

When I run the above test, I get `Number of calls: 0` on my spy and I also end up calling the *actual* `retrieveImageFromProxy` function, which I don't want to do.

How do I test that a basic demux factory like this works?

When I output the ingestFunction in the test, I get `[Function (anonymous)]`
If I remove the arrow function def in the return, so the return just looks like this: `return imageRetrievers.retrieveImageFromProxy(ingestObj.uri, ingestObj.usr, ingestObj.pw, ingestObj.authType, retry)`, there are no changes in test behavior nor what is output with the above console.log.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What is `imageRetrievers`?